# Store sql query on object

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to store a query in an object so that you can use it in a cursor or as a subquery of a bigger query? all this without using execute immediate?

Lets supose you want this:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  CNT NUMBER; 
  v1 varchar2(4000);
  SQL_QUERY view := SELECT table_name FROM USER_TABLES;
  CURSOR C1 IS 
    SQL_QUERY;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
    FETCH C1 INTO V1;
    dbms_output.put_line('name of the first table: '||v1);
  CLOSE C1;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT FROM SQL_QUERY;
  dbms_output.put_line('Count: '|| cnt);
end;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> "store a query in an object"

which is the definition of a view.

```
create view foo as select table_name from user_tables;
```

then

```
DECLARE
  CNT NUMBER; 
  v1 varchar2(4000);
  CURSOR C1 IS 
    select * from foo;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
    FETCH C1 INTO V1;
    dbms_output.put_line('name of the first table: '||v1);
  CLOSE C1;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT FROM (select null from foo);
  dbms_output.put_line('Count: '|| cnt);
end;
```

isn't that what you want?

Comment: Not really, i wanted a way to define a query wich i could use to encapsulate another query or use it in a cursor.

Comment: @JGS, Then you must use dynamic SQL, which is REF CURSOR or EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE etc...